# How to derive that total kinetic energy is conserved during the collision?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, collision

1. How to derive the below equation from scratch?
2. What law support this equation?
3. What is the name for it?
4. Does it refer to the conservation of kinetic energy?

Like law of conservation of momentum derived from newton's 3rd law.

$\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2 = \frac{1}{2}m_1v_1'^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2v_2'^2$

Where $U_1$ , $U_2$ initial velocities before collision of masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ and $V_1$ , $V_2$ final velocities after collision. This equation related to classical mechanics. And the above equation used for finding $V_1$ and $V_2$ for elastic collision in 1 dimension.

Comment: What are $U$ terms? Are they the initial velocities of m1 and m2? And what makes you think the equation is derived from Newton's 3rd law?

Comment: Newton's 3rd is the one about an action producing an equal an opp. one. The equation you provide looks like conservation of kinetic energy in a collision for non-relativistic mechanics. Is that what you meant it to be?

Comment: If you do mean conservation of kinetic energy in a collision, I believe the term you are looking for is "elastic collision".

Comment: Hello @BobaFit Yes this equation from classical mechanics for elastic collision in 1 dimension. How to drive the above equation?

Comment: Hi @BobD Yes i edited the question. $U_1$ and $U_2$ are the velocities before collision for masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ respectively.

Comment: Hi @KenMellendorf Yes above equation is related to elastic collision in 1 dimension. But previously someone told me kinetic energy never conserved. And you said conservation of kinetic energy. Pls tell me how the above equation derived?

Comment: Kinetic energy isn't conserved unless the coefficient of restitution is 1. If you want to check, there is a formula: $ v_1= \frac{(m_1-em_2)u_1 +m_2u_2(1+e)}{m_1+m_2} $ and $ v_2= \frac{(m_2-em_1)u_2 +m_1u_1(1+e)}{m_1+m_2} $ from these you can derive the kinetic energies and see that they don't get conserved for all values of $e$

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $m_1$ and $m_2$ are interacting with each other via some conservative force with a potential of the form $\phi(|x_2-x_1|)$. Then the Lagrangian is $$\mathcal{L}= \frac{1}{2}m_1 \dot x_1^2 + \frac{1}{2} m_2 \dot x_2^2 -\phi(|x_2-x_1|)$$
Since $\mathcal{L}$ does not depend explicitly on time then per Noether's theorem there is a conserved energy. It is given by $$\mathcal{H}=\sum_i \dot x_i \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot x_i}-\mathcal{L} $$$$\mathcal{H}= \frac{1}{2}m_1 \dot x_1^2 + \frac{1}{2} m_2 \dot x_2^2 +\phi(|x_2-x_1|)$$

Now suppose further that for $|x_2-x_1|>R$ we have $\phi(|x_2-x_1|)=0$ meaning that beyond a certain distance $R$ the energy stored in the potential goes to zero. Then if we start and end outside of that distance, $R_{initial}>R$ and $R_{final}>R$, we have $$\frac{1}{2}m_1 u_1^2 + \frac{1}{2} m_2 u_2^2 = \left. \mathcal{H} \right|_{R_{initial}} = \left. \mathcal{H} \right|_{R_{final}}=\frac{1}{2}m_1 v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2} m_2 v_2^2$$ where $u_i = \left. \dot x_i \right|_{R_{initial}}$ and $v_i = \left. \dot x_i \right|_{R_{final}}$

So this result holds whenever there is such a conservative interaction with a short range. Such interactions are called elastic collisions.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your support. Pls show this relation relation using newtonian mechanics. and i can not understand the concept KE and PE and when they conserved , i know the formulae not concept of energy. Explain it in simple way

Comment: This post seems to be the only one that demonstrates an understanding of the question and actually answers the question.

Comment: @123 The point is that in an elastic collision we assume there is some _conservative force_ between the two colliding masses. "Conservative" means that there is a potential energy function $\phi(|x_{2}-x_{1}|)$ such that $KE + \phi$ is always conserved. Now the key is that in an elastic collision, the specific realistic dynamics are usually too complicated to write down explicitly, but the fact that $KE + \phi$ is conserved is what allows us to _simplify_ our analysis. We know $\phi = 0$ before and after the collision, so then it follows that $KE_{\text{before}} = KE_{\text{after}}$. [...]

Comment: [...] This, combined with conservation of momentum, allows us to predict exactly the outcome of the elastic collision without knowing the specific intermediate details of the collision.

Comment: @123 I don’t know of a Newtonian based proof. I am skeptical that such a proof exists. It is not always possible to prove things in a specific way, and I think this is one of those cases. The key theorem here is Noether’s theorem which is probably the single most important theorem in all of physics. If you really want to be a “Deep Thinker of Physics” then you need to learn Noether’s theorem

Answer (score 1):

There is no law of conservation of kinetic energy, but you can derive conservation of energy by first using Newton's Second law to obtain the [Work Kinetic Energy Theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/469651/work-kinetic-energy-theorem). This states that the work done by the net force on an object is equal to the change in its kinetic energy:
$$
W_{F_{\rm net}} = \Delta K = \frac{1}{2} m v_f^2 -  \frac{1}{2} m v_i^2
$$
Then you can say that all forces are either conservative or non-conservative, and that the work done by conservative forces can be written as the (negative) change in potential energy:
\begin{align}
W_{F_{\rm net}} &= K_f - K_i\\
W_{F_{\rm non-conservative}} + W_{F_{\rm conservative}} &= K_f - K_i\\
W_{\rm nonconservative} + \left(- \Delta U\right) &= K_f - K_i\\
W_{\rm nonconservative} - \left( U_f - U_i\right) &= K_f - K_i \\
K_i + U_i + W_{\rm nonconservative} &= K_f + U_f\\
ME_i + W_{\rm nc} &= ME_f
\end{align}
This is the law of *conservation of energy*.  In the case that there is no work done by non-conservative forces ($W_{\rm nc}=0$), you obtain *conservation of mechanical energy* ($ME = K + U$).  And in the case that there is (1) no work done by non-conservative forces **and** (2) no change in the potential energy, you could write:
\begin{align}
K_i = K_f
\end{align}

Comment: Hi, For elastic collision in 1 dimension, why potential energy don't change. and what are the conditions when potential energy considered to be change.

Comment: In introductory physics situations, we essentially only have two conservative forces (and thus two associated potential energies): gravitation and springs.  If you have a collision in which the gravitational potential energy does not change (no change in height of the objects), and in which there are no springs (or they have the same compression before and after the collision), then there is no change in potential energy.

Answer (score 0):

In general, momentum is conserved in a collision, not kinetic energy.

Kinetic energy is conserved in elastic collisions, and you can use this condition as the definition of an elastic collion.

Comment: There must be some way to derive to above equation for elastic collision in 1 dimension. Pls explain it in words with phenomenon if possible.